# R: use min() within dplyr::mutate()

Tags: r, min, dplyr

```
require(plyr)
require(dplyr)    
set.seed(8)
    df <- 
      data.frame(
        v1 = runif(10, -1,1),
        v2 = runif(10, -1,1))
```

The problem:
How can I get the correct values into the `min()` function as part of `mutate()`- basically, I would like to assign `v3`as `v1` divided with the smallest of `v1` and `v2`.
This doesnt work:

```
  df <- 
         df %>% mutate(v3=ifelse(v1 !=0, v1/min(v1,v2), 0))
```

I guess I am missing something really simple.

Comment: You could use `pmin` i.e. `transform(df, v3=ifelse(v1!=0, v1/do.call(pmin, df), 0))`

Comment: Any particular reason you loading `plyr` package here? I don't remember which should be loaded first, but in this case you shouldn't load `plyr` at all.

Comment: Right, normally plyr first, but here only dplyr could be loaded.

Comment: Here I think it looking for min value of columns rather than rows.  You may have to wrap with with `do`, or best would be `pmin`

Comment: @akrun, perfect! Can you explain briefly the difference between `min` and `pmin`, or rather why the first does not work in a data frame like mine?

Comment: How about `df %>% mutate(v3 = (v1 != 0) * v1/pmin(v1,v2))`?

Comment: Here is a way using `do`, ie. `df %>% rowwise() %>% do(data.frame(., v3=(.$v1!=0)*.$v1/min(.$v1, .$v2)))`

Comment: Guys, how about posting some answers?

Comment: You can use `mutate` with `rowwise` - `df %>% rowwise %>% mutate(v3 = ifelse(v1 != 0, v1/min(v1, v2), 0))`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From the help page on `?min`:

> pmax and pmin take one or more vectors (or matrices) as arguments and
>   return a single vector giving the ‘parallel’ maxima (or minima) of the
>   vectors.

On the other hand:

> max and min return the maximum or minimum of all the values present in
>   their arguments

So you want to use `pmin` here. With dplyr, one option - as commented above - is like this:

```
df %>% mutate(v3 = (v1 != 0) * v1/pmin(v1,v2))
```

Nice side effect here is that you can avoid using `ifelse` and just mulitply with the logical vector (TRUE / FALSE which is then converted to 1 / 0).