# R - How can I choose the earliest date column from date columns?

Tags: r, date, min

I would like to get a column that has the earliest date in each row from multiple date columns.

My dataset is like this.

`df = data.frame( x_date = as.Date( c("2016-1-3", "2016-3-5", "2016-5-5")) , y_date = as.Date( c("2016-2-2", "2016-3-1", "2016-4-4")), z_date = as.Date(c("2016-3-2", "2016-1-1", "2016-7-1")) )`

`+---+-----------+------------+-----------+
|   |  x_date   |  y_date    |  z_date   |
+---+-----------+------------+-----------+
|1 | 2016-01-03 | 2016-02-02 |2016-03-02 |
|2 | 2016-03-05 | 2016-03-01 |2016-01-01 |
|3 | 2016-05-05 | 2016-04-04 |2016-07-01 |
+---+-----------+------------+-----------+`

I would like to get something like the following column.

`+---+---------------+
|   | earliest_date |
+---+---------------+
|1  | 2016-01-03    |
|2  | 2016-01-01    |
|3  | 2016-04-04    |
+---+---------------+`

This is my code, but it outputs the earliest date from the overall columns and rows....

`library(dplyr)
df %>% dplyr::mutate(earliest_date = min(x_date, y_date, z_date))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is `pmin`

```
df %>% 
   mutate(earliest_date = pmin(x_date, y_date, z_date))
#    x_date     y_date     z_date   earliest_date
#1 2016-01-03 2016-02-02 2016-03-02    2016-01-03
#2 2016-03-05 2016-03-01 2016-01-01    2016-01-01
#3 2016-05-05 2016-04-04 2016-07-01    2016-04-04
```

If we need only the single column, then `transmute` is the option

```
df %>%
    transmute(earliest_date = pmin(x_date, y_date,z_date))
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to do! [pmin()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070878/r-use-min-within-dplyrmutate) the function I need to use. Thank you very much.

Comment: Additionally, when I tried to use pmin() for rows with missing values, NAs, I needed to use ifelse() to deal with NAs. However, at that time, Date class was automatically converted to double type (precisely speaking, Date class information was removed). To keep class information of Date, I tried safe.ifelse() proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects) , and it's working fine.

Comment: @Toshihiro There is `na.rm` argument in `pmin` . By default, it is `FALSE` i.e. `pmin(x_date, y_date, z_date, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

You can `apply` rowwise to get minimum of the date (as the dates are already of class Date)

```
apply(df, 1, min)

#[1] "2016-01-03" "2016-01-01" "2016-04-04"
```

---

Or you can also use `pmin` with `do.call`

```
do.call(pmin, df)

#[1] "2016-01-03" "2016-01-01" "2016-04-04"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to transform your data set first if you want the output to be a data frame with columns in rows.

```
library(reshape2)
melt(df) %>% group_by(variable) %>% summarize(earliest_date = min(value))
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I had forgotten about that.